# UITableView Cell Updates When I Scroll

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm developing an iPhone Application, and I have a small issue, or so I think. I have a tableview and I got it to set the colors and labels of the cells by returning the cells in a method. Everything seems fine when I run it, the problem is when I scroll **the cell's color changes to that of the cell below or above.** I'm not sure how to solve this. I believe it's **updating the cell when I scroll** for some reason. How would I change this to only set the cell properties at first and not when I scroll?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    tableCellCount ++;

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

        UIColor * lightRed = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.1 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
        UIColor * darkRed = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.1 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
        UIColor * darkGray = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.15 alpha:1.0];

        NSLog(@"A");

        if (tableCellCount % 2 == 0) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = darkRed;
            cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = darkRed;
            cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = darkRed;
        } else {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = lightRed;
            cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = lightRed;
            cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = lightRed;
        }
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:darkGray];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}
```

### **Update**

I figured out the solution to my problem.

Here's the updated code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] 
                           objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"News_Icon@2x.png"];

    UIColor * lightRed = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.1 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor * darkRed = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.1 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor * darkGray = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.15 alpha:1.0];

    if (row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = darkRed;
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = darkRed;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = darkRed;
    } else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = lightRed;
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = lightRed;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = lightRed;
    }
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:darkGray];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    for(UIView *view in [tableView subviews]) {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"]) {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

---

Comment: For some reason I think you might get more accurate responses if you paste your code.

Comment: Please post your cell for row at index path method, I'm nearly certain that the error is there.

Comment: You need to upload your code for your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each cell in the table, there are properties you want to set the first time only when the cell gets created and there are other properties you want to set each time.

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:anyId];
if(cell==nil)
{
    // Properties to set the first time when the cell is created only
}
// Properties to set each time

return cell;
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I implemented this into my code, and for some reason it's not working properly. I posted my code above. Could you give me some advice as to how to fix what I have?

Comment: The alternating color part needs to be executed everytime not only the first time so try moving it out, also it should depend on [indexPath row] instead of counting the cells yourself using tableCellCount as this method is called everytime even when the cell is reused.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! That fixed it, it was getting really annoying

Comment: Making these properties nil before setting them solve the problem in most cases. eg.cell.textlabel.text = nil;

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing cell views. Check the method in your table view controller `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`and you for sure are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. You have to set color values to that reused cell.

Comment: I believe what is causing this is this line:

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

How could I fix this? I just implemented the Table View so I'm not really familiar with the cells

Comment: No, that is not the point. For sure that sentence is in a if() structure and is executed if cell is nil, that is, if a previous `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`has returned a nil value. But, if it returns a valid cell, then you have to change it to your desired colors.

Comment: To clarify it a little. That line of code you have written creates a new cell, but you only create a new cell if there are not another to be reused. Check the customization you are doing to the cell after creating it and do the same with the reused cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with cells being reused.  `UITableViews` recycle cells.  So if you are not correctly handling this in your `tableview:cellForRowAtIndex:` method you will get strange results when you scroll.  Always assume that the cell you are setting up may already be setup as another cell.